# Print is printing elements of linked list without loop

Tags: python, object, linked-list, f-string

I am creating linked list. In my linked list i have **str** method in both classes Node and LinkedList. What i was trying to do is, print object in readable format whenever i print object to console. So i used **str** method in Node class, but i have no idea how this is printing all elements in the linked list without any loop whenever i use print() function.

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    
    def __str__(self):
        if self.head is not None:
            return str(self.head)
        return 'empty linked list'
    
    def insert(self, data):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(data)
        else:
            head = self.head
            while head.next is not None:
                head = head.next
            head.next = Node(data)
        

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.data}\n{self.next}"
        
        
elems1 = [1,2,3,4]

llist1 = LinkedList()

for elem in elems1:
    llist1.insert(elem)
 
print(llist1)
```

I figured out that using {self.next} in **str** method in Node class is causing such behaviour but i have now idea how this is working.

Comment: The `__str__` method for a node prints the current data element and the next node, which of course calls `__str__` on the next node, which calls `__str__` on the next node, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets go down (or up if you prefer) the call stack.

1. `print(llist1)` this calls the method `LinkedList.__str__`
2. that `LinkedList.__str__` then calls `str(self.head)` which then calls the method `Node.__str__`
3. that `Node.__str__` then returns the expression `f"{self.data}\n{self.next}"`
4. in evaluating that expression, you then must call the self.next *and* then stringifyit. (putting that expression `self.next` in that f-string calls the `__str__` method)
5. so now you've called `Node.__str__` on `self.next` which as we know will then call *its* `self.next` and so on and so on until `self.next == None` in which case there's no more `__str__` method to call
6. `self.next` will return the empty string  and stop the recursive call stack

You've created a recursive program without realizing it.